# How do I find the mean of each row of grouped columns in a database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have grouped columns on the basis of their names and I have 3 columns in each group.I am not able to get the average of each row of each group.
For Example

Group 1

row 1: 1 2 3
row 2: 4 5 6
row 3: 7 8 9

Group 2

row 1: 4 2 3
row 2: 4 8 6
row 3: 7 8 12
Output

Group 1
---------Mean
row 1 :  2
row 2 :  5
row 3 :  8

Group 2
---------Mean
row 1 :  3
row 2 :  6
row 3 :  9

When I apply c=grouped.agg('mean',axis=0) I get this error "Numpy operations are not valid with groupby. Use .groupby(...).mean() instead"

Groupby.mean(axis=0) does not work either

Comment: "> get the average of each row of each group."

what does that even mean?
What do you want, average of each column?

Comment: @SadafShafi I want the average of each row not of a data frame but of groups created from that data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need processing values per rows use:

```
s = df.set_index(['a','b']).mean(axis=1)
print (s)
a        b    
Group 1  row 1    2.0
         row 2    5.0
         row 3    8.0
Group 2  row 1    3.0
         row 2    6.0
         row 3    9.0
dtype: float64
```

If need `mean` values per groups use this trick:

```
s1 = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.to_numpy()))
#for old pandas versions
#s1 = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.values))
print (s1)
a        b    
Group 1  row 1    2.0
         row 2    5.0
         row 3    8.0
Group 2  row 1    3.0
         row 2    6.0
         row 3    9.0
dtype: float64
```

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
         a      b  c  d   e
0  Group 1  row 1  1  2   3
1  Group 1  row 2  4  5   6
2  Group 1  row 3  7  8   9
3  Group 2  row 1  4  2   3
4  Group 2  row 2  4  8   6
5  Group 2  row 3  7  8  12
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this but I'm getting this error : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @meerakapoor - You can use `s1 = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.values))` instead `s1 = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.to_numpy()))`